# Microphone input in Linux

Tags: linux, driver, microphone, waveform, soundcard

I have a microphone connected to the mic input of a laptop (OS is Ubuntu 12.04). Is there a program that I can use to view live (and record) the analog waves from the microphone? Is there any program in the kernel that I can use?

Thanks.
(Why do I need it? I am making a magnetic stripe reader and I want to be able to look at the ''raw'' biphasic waves from a magnetic head: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmtS8zaPPUM)

Comment: Try arecord if you want to pipe samples into a simple program or look at alsa sample code.  Also audacity is good for manual experiments.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Audacity seems to be the software that I'm looking for. Thank you.